# Why does the device names in lsusb differ from dmesg?

Tags: usb

When I plug my USB device in, I see in the system with `dmesg`,

```
usb 5-2.2.2.2: new low-speed USB device number 48 using xhci_hcd
usb 5-2.2.2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1130, idProduct=0202, bcdDevice= 1.00
usb 5-2.2.2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 5-2.2.2.2: Product: Panic Button
input: Panic Button as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:20:00.0/0000:21:02.0/0000:22:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.2/5-2.2.2/5-2.2.2.2/5-2.2.2.2:1.0/0003:1130:0202.0063/input/input136
hid-generic 0003:1130:0202.0063: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Device [Panic Button] on usb-0000:22:00.0-2.2.2.2/input0
input: Panic Button as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:20:00.0/0000:21:02.0/0000:22:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.2/5-2.2.2/5-2.2.2.2/5-2.2.2.2:1.1/0003:1130:0202.0064/input/input137
hid-generic 0003:1130:0202.0064: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.10 Device [Panic Button] on usb-0000:22:00.0-2.2.2.2/input1
```

However, with `lsusb` I see,

```
Bus 005 Device 048: ID 1130:0202 Tenx Technology, Inc. Rocket Launcher
```

Why is there a discrepancy here? How does the kernel's device database say

> Product: Panic Button

While the lsusb device database says,

> Tenx Technology, Inc. Rocket Launcher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB devices provide a few different pieces of information about themselves; notably, a vendor identifier, product identifier, vendor name and product name. The latter two aren’t always accurate, and a separate database of vendor and product names is maintained by volunteers, [the USB ID repository](http://www.linux-usb.org).

The kernel shows the name the device gives itself, whereas `lsusb` (in its default view) shows the name mapped to the product identifier in [the USB ID repository](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids).

`lsusb -v` shows both pieces of information: the “iProduct” entry shows the product name returned by the device (as shown in `dmesg`), the “idProduct” entry shows the product id returned by the device and the entry matching that (and the vendor id) from the USB ID database.